# Cassandra Update query | timestamp column as clustering key

Tags: cassandra

I have a table in cassandra with following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE user_album_entity (
    userId text,
    albumId text,
    updateDateTimestamp timestamp,
    albumName text,
    description text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((userId), updateDateTimestamp)
);
```

The query required to get data would have a where userId = xxx order by updateTimestamp. Hence the schema had updateDateTimestamp.

Problem comes in updating the column of table.The query is: Update the album information for user where user id = xxx. But as per specs,for update query I would need the exact value of updateDateTimestamp which in normal world scenario, an application would never send.

What should be the answer to such problems since I believe this a very common use case where select query requires ordering on timestamp. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your table structure allows the same album to have multiple records with the only difference being the timestamp (the clustering key).

Three possible solutions:

1. Remove the clustering key and sort your data at application level.
2. Remove the clustering key and add a [Secondary Index](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/usePrimaryIndex.html) to the timestamp field.
3. Remove the clustering key and create a [Materialized View](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-views) to perform the query.

Comment: One thing which I realized is definitely updateDateTimestamp should never be part of your clustering key. All examples of KillrChat shows that the order by date columns are creation/uploaded date etc etc. Still it sounds a bit weird to be since the mapping is 1:n, if I keep userId as partition key and albumId and creationDate as clustering key. If any day I have to update album name for all users I have to do async multiple updates since I can't do IN operation on userId being the very first key. Am I right @xmas79 on that or there is a hidden better way to do that.

Comment: Don't use option 2 and 3. MVs are labeled as experimental, Secondary indexes have a lot of downsides including massive performance penalties with cluster growth.

Answer (score 0):

If your usecase is such that each partition will contain exactly one row,
then you can model your table like:

`CREATE TABLE user_album_entity (
    userId text,
    albumId text static,
    updateDateTimestamp timestamp,
    albumName text static,
    description text static,
    PRIMARY KEY ((userId), updateDateTimestamp)
);`

modelling the table this way enables Update query to be done in following way:
`UPDATE user_album_entity SET albumId = 'updatedAlbumId' WHERE userId = 'xyz'`

Hope this helps.